# Deletion of unique class object pointers in a static vector

Tags: c++

Suppose we create a simple class called Window, and want to keep track of all the windows we have with a vector of `std::unique_ptr`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Window {
public:
    static std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Window>> MemberPointers;
private:
    int width;
    int height;

};
```

Where we allocate a pointer to the created object in the constructor for this class.

According to Bjarne Stroustrup's "A Tour of C++", `std::unique_ptr` gets deallocated when it goes out of scope, just like a regular local variable. Does that mean, in the deconstructor for this class, I would not need to call anything to `delete` the vector element that points to this object?

If not, how could I delete the correct object with `std::erase` and `std::remove_if`?

Comment: Why do you use `static`?

Comment: As `MemberPointers` is `static` it's lifetime will last until `main` exits.

Comment: I want to instantiate multiple objects of this class, and still have the vector that points to the objects be part of the class. Without `static`, every object would have its own vector, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstood the purpose of `unique_ptr`.
It assumes the object to which it holds a pointer is allocated by `new`,
and `delete`s that object in its destructor. Example:

```
void f() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> ptr{new int(123)};
} //the int allocated by new is deleted here by ptr's dtor
```

Suppose you implement the class like this:

```
class Window {
public:
    Window(int w, int h) :width{w}, height{h}
    {
        MemberPointers.emplace_back(this);
    }
    static std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Window>> MemberPointers;
private:
    int width;
    int height;
};
```

Then, in `main`, you do this:

```
Window win{1000, 500};
```

Now `Window::MemberPointers` contains one element:
a `unique_ptr` holding `&win`.

Finally, when the whole program has finished,
and the dtor of `MemberPointers` is called.
The `unique_ptr` tries to `delete win`. 
Note that `win` is not allocated by `new`,
so that results in undefined behavior.

Summary:
Your purpose is **to remove the pointer itself from MemberPointers**
when the pointee is destructed,
but the fact is **it tries to `delete` the pointee,**
**leaving the pointer itself in MemberPointers still.**

The correct design is simple: no `unique_ptr`s.

```
class Window {
public:
    Window(int w, int h) :width{w}, height{h}
    {
        MemberPointers.emplace_back(this);
    }
    ~Window()
    {
        auto p = std::remove(MemberPointers.begin(), MemberPointers.end(), this);
        MemberPointers.erase(p, MemberPointers.end());
    } // remove this from MemberPointers
    static std::vector<Window*> MemberPointers;
private:
    int width;
    int height;
};
```

Or, even better and more efficient, with `std::set`:

```
class Window {
public:
    Window(int w, int h) :width{w}, height{h}
    {
        MemberPointers.emplace(this);
    }
    ~Window()
    {
        MemberPointers.erase(this);
    } // remove this from MemberPointers
    static std::set<Window*> MemberPointers;
private:
    int width;
    int height;
};
```

The design with `std::vector` is of complexity O(*n*) where *n* is the number of objects; the design with `std::set` is of complexity O(log(*n*)) (significantly more efficient provided that you have created really a LOT of objects).

Comment: Great answer. I didn't think it could be this easy with `std::set`

Comment: Note that if you want this class to be copied or moved, you must explicitly provide a copy/move ctor/op= or such-created objects will not be tracked by MemberPointers. If you do not, you can declare the copy/move ctor/op= as **private**, so users will not copy or move it by accident. (Note that if you have C++11, you can also use `=delete`)

Comment: `unordered_set` would be even more efficient in terms of complexity (O(1))

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `std::erase`, `std::remove_if`, and any other function that removes elements from an `std::vector` (including the destructor), call the destructor of each element they removes.

Calling the destructor of a `unique_ptr`, destroys the object it points to.
This can happen either by going out of scope (if it's in the stack) or explicitly deleting a pointer to it if it's in the heap.

In this case, the `MemberPointers` vector will be destroyed right before the termination of your program, which will call the destructor of its elements (`unique_ptr`s allocated on the heap), so no memory will be leaked.